# Extremes of function

Tags: calculus

How could I find the maxima, minima, and inflection points of the function $y=x^{11}e^{-7x}$ ?

If I set the derivative $11x^{10}e^{-7x}-7x^{11}e^{-7x}$ to $0$, it is clear that there must be an extreme point at $x=\dfrac{11}{7}$.
I can't seem to get further than that..

Comment: Your derivative expression is incorrect, have a look at the second term.

Comment: Oh, right, I've edited it. Thanks.